# How do I test code with serious side-effect?

Tags: unit-testing, testing

Unittest is important during the development. But, testing some code is not easy.

If I have some code like that:

```
class Filesystem():

    def destroy(self, fs):
        os.system("mkfs.ext4 %s" % fs)
        #assert(self.size(fs) == 0)
```

I can't destroy an filesystem for a test.

For this situation, I can create a file-based drive on UNIX for the test.

But, if it is an API class:

```
class Blog():

    def post(self, text):
        blog.library.post(self.access_key, text)
```

I don't want to post a blog article for the test.

What should I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For unit tests:

Your class shouldn't interact with `blog.library` directly but through some intermediate layer that you're injecting as a `Blog` class dependency. For tests you create a mock for it and assert that expected method was invoked with expected parameters.

For functional/integration tests:

you set up a dummy blog engine and perform real posts. Then check that post really appears on the page with `http` request.

Answer (score 3):

Not an expert, but I believe mocking is the answer.

You don't want to post an article, and in fact your test code doesn't expect a **REAL** article at all, you just need to fake an object(which we calling it: mocking) and let it **behaves** like a real article, so that your real code will get its work done, that's enough.

Just remember, the purpose in testing is to make sure your code is working correctly. In OO programming, we treated everything as objects, so when you post an article, it actually create an object which represent an real article in out real world. Mocking a fake object is enough to express your code's behaviors, so you don't have to write a real article at all, just to prove your code will create an object which is likely a post is pretty enough.

Answer (score 1):

As the others have said, mocking will come to your aid here. There are a number of mocking frameworks available - I prefer Mockito as it seems the most intuitive ( to me anyway )

I find [this article](http://gojko.net/2009/10/23/mockito-in-six-easy-examples/) covers the basics very quickly and clearly

Mockito cannot mock static methods, but can be used in tandem with PowerMock to achieve this. Plenty of examples exist on the web in general ( and SO in particular ) on how to do this. Having said that, I always feel that having to fall back on PowerMock generally points towards something smelly in my code.

EDIT

Just realised that I'm talking from a Java perspective and that doesn't appear to be your current envirnoment

END EDIT

Answer (score 1):

Like Albert said, it should be `mock up entity`.

In .NET, I make these methods that you want to test `virtual` so that I can extend the real entity like `Blog` in a `MockedBlog` now this `MockedBlog` would have an `override` method of `Post()` and I check that Mm test is reaching this method like this:

```
public class MockedBlog : Blog
{
    public void override Post(string text)
    {  PostMethodWasCalled = true; }

    public bool PostMethodWasCalled {get;set;}
}
```

In the test, I would do something like this

```
var mockup = new MockedBlog();
// do the preparation, then post
mockup.Post("hello world");
Assert.IsTrue(mockup.PostMethodWasCalled);
```